# SSIS: Check file for row delimiter and dynamicly update row delimiter in Flat File Connection Manager at run time

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am importing about 50 or so txt files into a SQL Server table. All the files have the same layout except that for some files the row delimiter used was {CR}{LF} and for others {LF} was used.

Ideally I will be asking the person who creates the txt files to stick with the same delimiter moving forward but I would like to know if there is a way that I can scan the file (maybe using a C# script) in order to capture the delimiter used in the file to then be able to update the Flat File Connection Manager's Row delimiter dynamically at run time.

Is this possible? If so, does anyone have an example of how to accomplish (or a better solution)?

Comment: I just thought of a simple fix for my specific situation. Since I know the delimiter will either be {CR}{LF} or {LF} I can just add a Failure redirect from the dataflow task that fails to another data flow task containing the alternate/correct delimiter.I could also redirect to a task that switches between the 2 different delimiters and then goes back up to the top of the loop so we wont need 2 different dataflow tasks

Comment: Update: I just switched my delimiter from {CR}{LF} to {LF} in the Flat File Connection Manager and now all my files load correctly.... the {LF} delimiter in the connection manager works for both {CR}{LF} and {LF} delimited files but the {CR}{LF} delimtier will only work with {CR}{LF} delimited files.

Comment: {CR}{LF} indicates both row start and end, {LF} shows just the start. If your going to parse the columns you'll need to get the correct delimiter but if your just reading them in it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a Easy way [here](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/03/23/fix-inconsistent-line-terminators-in-ssis/)

You Just need to Set an Expression to Replace the '/r'(CR) in Data Flow Task

Just Awesome trick that can accept both CRLF and LF within a SSIS Package

Comment: very easy & good one

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Workaround

You can change the flat file row delimiter to `LF` *(from the flat file connection manager)*. so it will prevent package failure, and add a Script component that remove the `CR` value from the last column in every row

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    If Not Row.InColumn_IsNull AndAlso _
       Not String.IsnullOrEmpty(row.inColumn.Trim) Then

        Row.outColumn = Row.InColumn.TrimEnd(CChar(vbCr))

    Else

        Row.outColumn_IsNull = True        

    End If

End Sub
```

*Also you can achieve this with a derived column transformation with a similar expression*

```
Replace([inColumn],"\r","")
```

OR *(only remove last character if it is `CR`)*

```
RIGHT([inColumn],1) == "\r" ? LEFT([inColumn],LEN([inColumn]) - 1) : [inColumn]
```